# Complexity of a nested binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Does anyone know how to calculate the complexity of a nested binary search tree? I have implemented a nested binary search tree to a depth of 3 BSTs.

EDIT: I apologize for the confusion, I had meant that each node of the BST would point to the root node of another BST. The complexity I was asking for was time complexity of search, update, and delete (basic operations). I had assume that since the time complexity of a BST was O(log(n)), the time complexity of a nested BST in terms of search, update, and delete wouldn't differ that much.

Comment: Complexity of what? Time complexity of some operation?

Comment: Define *"complexity of a nested binary search tree"*.  For that matter, define *"nested binary search tree"* (do you mean subtree?)

Comment: what do you mean by complexity? space? a particular operation? please expand

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I had meant that each node of the BST would point to the root node of another BST. The complexity I was asking for was time complexity of search, update, and delete (basic operations). I had assume that since the time complexity of a BST was O(log(n)), the time complexity of a nested BST in terms of search, update, and delete wouldn't differ that much.

Comment: *"I had meant that each node of the BST would point to the root node of another BST."* - That is the definition of a (single) BST :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "nested" you mean that each node of a particular tree points to the root of another tree, up to 3 levels deep.

Well a binary search tree is generally going to be O(log n) lookup time. Since you're doing 3 lookups, that's O(log a * log b * log c). Of course that's assuming that they're well balanced and everything. The worst case for a binary search tree is O(n) (think of a tree where it's basically a straight line). Then the worst case time would be O(a * b * c).

And for the record, a b and c are the number of elements in the first tree, second nested tree, and third doubly-nested tree, respectively.

Comment: Why did this earn a downvote? Given the vagueness of the question, this is as reasonable a guess at what OP was after as anything.

Comment: Thanks, @Ted Hopp. I stated my assumption, if you don't agree then simply don't accept it.

Comment: @Ted @Chris: Because it's actually `O(log a + log b + log c) = O(log(abc))`, which is the depth you'd get by treating the multiple "nested" trees as one big tree.  Which makes sense, because *all* nodes in any tree are themselves nested trees, by definition.  It is this property which makes recursion so useful when dealing with trees.

Comment: @BlueRaja: You are correct! Yes after all it's not like each subtree is being called by each node on the way down, is it? I was thinking in terms of loops. Good call.

Comment: I had originally thought that the time complexity would be O(log a * log b * log c), but I wasn't sure if this was correct. I think BlueRaja's answer would make more sense.

Comment: What would be the Time Complexity of Building a nested Binary Search Tree for every node in an Array of size `n`?