# Time complexity of tree of trees of trees of [...]

Tags: recursion, tree, time-complexity

Insertion into **balanced** search tree is O(log n).

What'd be the time complexity of insertion into tree of trees of trees of trees of [...]? (this continues `k` times). So each node of the main tree is tree of trees of ... `k` times.

For simplicity let's assume:

- each tree's height is `n`
- starting from the main parent tree, going through `k` trees and finally inserting into the innermost tree
- all trees are balanced search trees

Putting aside how would the balancing process work in such a structure.

My initial *guess* was that it's `O(k log n)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the main tree have any specific properties?

Comment: Yes, it's balanced search tree as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the main tree is just a random tree with no specific property, then to insert a new element we can search the main tree in `O(n)` time to find the appropriate sub-tree to insert the key in. This would be `O(nlogn)`. However, if the main tree and all the sub-trees are balanced, then the whole thing is just a balanced tree and insert will take `O(logn)` as usual.

Comment: Based on @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft 's response in a comment to the linked post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5572524/8974764
I think it should be `O(log n + log n + log n + ... [k times])`, which is further equivalent to `O(log (n * n * n * ... [k times]))`, which results in `O(log n^k)` or `O(k log n)`.

Comment: Hence: can I neglect the `k` if it's small value resulting in `O(log n)`? And if `k` was large, then use `O(k log n)`?

Comment: If the tree is similar to the tree in that question (each node in a sub-tree points to its own root), then yes `O(klogn)` seems correct. Assuming the main tree has `n` sub-trees, each of those has `n` sub-trees, and the innermost trees each has  `n` nodes (not height).